# Microsoft Excel - Formula query

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create a formula as follows:

IF SUM of Columns A2:D2 = 0, then excel should populate in column E, the value of "NO", else it should be a default "YES".

This is what I've tried

```
=IF(SUM(R3:V3)="0", "NO","YES")
```

Comment: I tried the following: =IF(SUM(R3:V3)="0", "NO","YES"), but seeing as am a relatively new excel user, getting stumped, since the function isnt returning the value I want. Thought someone on this site could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this to your E column

```
=IF(SUM(A2:D2)=0,"No","Yes")
```

This works and is tested.

The difference, is you've used

```
=IF(SUM(R3:V3)="0", "NO","YES")
```

note the `"0"` in quote marks where as I have `0`

Comment: :):):) this is perfect, it worked!! Thanks for the help.